# Accidentally Deleted a Globally Reusable Workflow On SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

In trying to figure out how to edit Globally Reusable Workflows automated emails I deleted my Collection Feedback Form. I REALLY need it back. It does not appear in SharePoint Designer, on my SharePoint site workflows, or anywhere.

I do not know who to contact to get it back or if there is a way to restore it.

PLEASE HELP. [image]

Answer (score 1):

**First,** you **can't delete the Globally reusable workflow**, you just can `copy and move` it to build your own based on it.

**Second,** it Looks like you have deleted a Reusable Workflow that it's `SharePoint 2010 workflow` and can be easily restored from the **Recycle bin**.

> **Unfortunately,** you will lose all workflow history data for this workflow.

---

**Restore Deleted Workflow**

- Open site collection > Site content > click on Recycle Bin.
- Check the workflow name > Click on Retore Selection.

[image]

- Go back to the SharePoint Designer, Workflow, you will find it.
- Publish it again.